# ScreenCapture on OS X Retina

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, retina-display, cgimageref

I am trying to do a screen capture on OS X. My solution works properly on macbook pro. But I am facing some problems on Retina displays.

I try to get the current resolution using `CGDisplayPixelsHigh/CGDisplayPixelsWide`. It returns the correct resolution (the one I see in Preferences) on Retina but the image returned by `CGDisplayCreateImage` gives an image of double the resolution.

This is the code I am using

```
int activeDisplay;
size_t screenX, screenY;

activeDisplay = CGMainDisplayID();
screenY = CGDisplayPixelsHigh(activeDisplay);
screenX = CGDisplayPixelsWide(activeDisplay);

CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplay);
```

Is there a way to capture an image of the resolution I am seeing in Preferences in Retina displays? Also can some one explain why this is happening?

Comment: If you have Retina display, the Preferences page is supposed to show scaling controls, not resolution numbers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any documents that explains why I need to provide 2x resolution images for retina? I am trying to see the technical difference between retina and normal displays.

Comment: The technical difference is that the retina displays have higher pixel density. The image which you get is the actual size of your display in pixels. Most of the APIs in OS X return sizes and coordinates in logical points.